# bash: failed to get array length

Tags: bash

It is said that if variable args is of type array then `${#args}` is the length of the array.

`${#args}` is used to display the script params number as follows, but it is not as expected.

test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(`echo $@`)
echo "param count:"${#args}
echo "p1,p2,p3: "${args[0]},${args[1]},${args[2]}
```

The output "param count" is 1 but not 5 which is the count of script params.

```
> bash test1.sh a b c d e
param count:1
p1,p2,p3: a,b,c
```

Comment: Why the `echo`? Should be just `args=( "$@" )`

Comment: And `${#args[@]}` for the length.

Comment: Reading https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html might help understand the proper syntax for the length expansion. (`${#args}` is equivalent to `${#args[0]}`)

Comment: You seem to confuse bash and zsh here. `${#args}` (or simpler `$#args` is the array length in zsh. In bash, you have to write it like Shawn explained.

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 2):

> It is said that if variable args is of type array then `${#args}` is the length of the array.

It may be said by someone, but not by the bash manual. `${#args[*]}` or `${#args[@]}` are the length of the array.

Because

> referencing  an  array  variable  without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.

`${#args}` is the same as `${#args[0]}`, which is the length in characters of `${args[0]}`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using arrays you can print directly the variables. Something like can do the work:

```
echo $#
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
echo ${!i}
done
```

`$#` is the number of input arguments